# EditText and Button are not working in android fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, geocoding, android-button

This is my fragment class with an editText to search any place and a button to perform the search. I am getting error with the button, when I touch on it, the app gets stopped.

```
public class GMapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    MapFragment fragment;
    EditText location_tf;
    Button button;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gmap, container, false);
            location_tf = (EditText)rootView.findViewById (R.id.TFaddress);
            button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Bsearch);


            location_tf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
            List<Address> addressList = null;
            if(location != null || !location.equals(""))
            {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(),Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location , 1);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude() , address.getLongitude());
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            }
        }
            }
        );
            initilizeMap();
            return rootView;

            }




         private void initilizeMap()
        {
            MapFragment fragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
               if (fragment != null){
                   fragment.getMapAsync(this);

               }

        }
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        }

         @Override
        public void onPause() {

            final FragmentManager fragManager = this.getFragmentManager();
            final Fragment fragment = fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if(fragment!=null){
                fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            super.onPause();

            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            final FragmentManager fragManager = this.getFragmentManager();
            final Fragment fragment = fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            if(fragment!=null){
                fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
            }
        }
        }
```

this is my xml file for the fragment, edit text field and a search button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content">


<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content">

<EditText 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="183dp" 
android:id="@+id/TFaddress"/>

<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/Bsearch" 
android:onClick="onClick" 
android:layout_gravity="right" 
android:text="Search" 
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<fragment 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" 
android:id="@+id/map"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my logcat:

```
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057): Process: com.cubecode.mapdhaka, PID: 29057
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class com.cubecode.mapdhaka.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'Bsearch'
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3844)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18779)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClick [class android.view.View]
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:864)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3837)
05-20 14:26:23.506: E/AndroidRuntime(29057):    ... 11 more
```

I haven't found any solution by searching, so I seeking help from u guys. plz see this and give me a solution

Comment: see the problem @Blackbelt

Comment: delete this line from your xml `android:onClick="onClick" `. You can set the onClickListener programmatically

Comment: I am having trouble because I am using fragment, there is not much of solution for fragment. so I have posted here to get solution. If u remove the duplicate tag that would be helpful. As I am new, help me to learn something @ Blackbelt

Comment: I have set the button programmatically but I am having error. So can u help me or let others help me by removing the duplicate tag?@Blackbelt

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: I am not getting the real problem actually. I have tried everything but everytime I get different error. sometimes I get null pointer,  sometimes illegalStateexception.

Comment: Can u tell me how to use the button to get my geo coder work from the edit text? u have seen the class, just guide what should I change?@Blackbelt .